# Accesing session variables during ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, list

I have created session variable during the ajax call. The session variables are available once I refresh the page. But as I am using ajax call the whole page will not be refreshed. only a part of the div is refreshed.

please refer below:

```
//during ajax call
request.getSession().setAttribute("hi","hiList");
```

So I want to get the list using request.getSession().getAttribute("hi");

how do I get that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that above code in your jsp ?

Comment: no in the backend java class. @HarshulPandav